# Use Container/DependencyResolver in other dll

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, autofac

I'm trying to get myself familiar with `MVC3` and `autofac` but I've encountered small problem that I'm having trouble resolving.

I am using `autofac` integrated with `MVC3` and all works well, pages are loading correctly, dependencies are being injected and that's  cool. What's bugging me is how to use `autofac`'s `Container` or `MVC`'s `DependencyResover` in class library project.
I'm trying to create static class that will help me handle domain events. I simply want to be able to call the method with event parameter and everything should be handeled by this class. Here is code:

```
public static IContainer Container { get; set; }
public static void Raise<T>(T e) where T : IDomainEvent
{
    foreach (var eventHandler in DomainEventManager.Container.Resolve<IEnumerable<EventHandlers.Handles<T>>>())
    {
        eventHandler.Handle(e);
    }
}
```

As you can see it's pretty straightforward and everything would work great if it wasn't `MVC` approach. Some of my dependencies are registeres as `InstancePerHttpRequest` (`NHibernate`' session), while other are registered as `InstancePerDependency` or `SingleInstance`. Thus when I try to use `container` created in my UI project, I get exception that there is no `httpRequest` tag available.

How can i reuse the `Container` created in web project to get access to all of it's features, including `InstancePerHttpRequest` and `httpRequest` tag?

Or maybe there is other solution to my problem? I was thinking about using delegate function to obtain event handlers, but I cannot (can I?) create generic delegate that I would not need to initialize with concrete type at time of assignment.

Why I want to do this using static class is basically every `entity` and `aggregate` or `service` needs to be able to raise domain event. Injecting `EventManager` into every one of these would be troublesome and static class is exactly what would resolve all my problems.

If anyone could help me get my head around it I would be grateful.
Cheers, Pako

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be referencing your container directly from your app code. This looks like the Service Locator anti-pattern. The correct action is to pass your objects the services they need to do their jobs, usually done through constructor parameters. BUT... if you are going to insist on depending on a global static, then at least model `EventManager` as a singleton, such that usage would look like:

```
EventManager.Current.Raise<SomeEvent>(someObject);
```

and then you can set `EventManager.Current` equal to a properly constructed instance when your app is initialized.

Comment: I agree with you that usually you should not do something like this, however this is, lets say, special case. Injecting this class into every object in my domain would be simply troublesome. Creating `singleton` does not seem very different from having static class and I think it would have the same problem with obtaining event handlers as static class does, it would throw exception that `httpRequest` tag is not present.

Comment: The difference between the singleton and the static class is that the singleton would allow you to replace the instance with a more testable/mockable version in your automated tests.

Comment: As for the httpRequest tag part, if you intended to use the same exact container in a non-web context, then don't register your services with InstancePerHttpRequest. I usually use InstancePerLifetimeScope() which will be functionally the same as IPHR unless you're explicitly creating your own lifetimescopes.

Comment: As for testing event manager - I don't think that this is necessary. The class is very simple and it works just fine with tests - I simply inject mockups of event handlers and event manager passes them to entities in unit tests. And about `InstancePerLifetimeScope` I think that this will give me exactly the same problem as IPHR, since no other scope is visible but root.